# How can you run autohotkey script in background only with PID available?

Tags: script, autohotkey

I like to run an autohotkey script in background inside a virtual machine (sandboxie). The script will press f1-f8 keys in an endless loop. It is supposed to have effects on a game which runs on the virtual machine as well.

I'm pretty sure I need to use `ControlSend`, so it would look like that

```
ControlSend, , {f1}, HERE_COMES_THE_WINDOW_NAME
```

but i cannot use window name for some reason so I like to use PID instead of it.

Is that possible to do and if yes how?

The virtual machine looks like this (Game.exe is the game where I like to run that Autohotkey script):

[image]

Comment: Sandboxie isn’t a virtual machine.  Virtualization isn’t used by Sandboxie at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the only way you can interact with an application running in Sandboxie is through the window interface that the application provides.  Any kind of direct interface is likely going to be abstracted by SandBoxie if it's running the program under a different user or whatnot to protect it from directly accessing the file system and other user processes (not really sure how it works since I don't have it, just a guess).

If you can't figure out which window to use (i.e., which window to send keystrokes to), try the `Window Spy` application that comes with AutoHotkey.

Unfortunately, when using `ControlSend`, things don't always work like you may expect them to.  You may also want to look at trying the `ahk_parent` option for `ControlSend`.

In general, it may also be more reliable to try and detect and subsequently use the window handle (`HWND`) instead of something like `ahk_exe game.exe`--i.e., you don't have to worry about the window handle getting interpreted as anything other than the window handle, and you can 100% confirm that you have the right window handle.

Another useful tool for detecting multi-layered windows so you can try different controls and/or HWND values to send to, is Microsoft `Spy++`, which will show you the hierarchy and control names for the windows.  This may allow you to find the right control value to send to if the parent window doesn't work.  Again, this really only useful if you're using `ControlSend` to try and send something to a window that's not active--if you're just using `SendInput` to send something to an active window then `Spy++` isn't going to tell you anything useful.

Circling back to the original question on accessing the process by PID, the only value here would be to potentially guarantee you have the right window handle linked to a particular PID (but you would still be sending something to the window, so this is just an indirect way to get the window).  To do that, you could use the code below below.

Code Excerpt From: [How To Pause An External Process](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/19206-how-to-pause-an-external-process/)

```
DetectHiddenWindows, ON ; You should avoid this for your purpose!!
PID := DllCall("GetCurrentProcessId")

Gui, 1:Show, x0 y0   w200 h100, Test Window1
Gui, 2:Show, x205 y0 w200 h100, Test Window2

WinGet, List, List, ahk_pid %PID%

Loop %List%
{
WinGetTitle, Title, % "ahk_id " List%A_Index%
Wins .= Title "`n"
}

MsgBox, 0, Windows for PID: %PID%,  %Wins%

ExitApp
```

Also going back to the original question:

> i cannot use window name for some reason

You didn't state exactly what symptoms led you to believe this, but I'm guessing it might be something along the lines of "it just didn't work".

If that is the case, I would also recommend trying to simplify the problem if possible and get it to work with something that can be definitively tested.  For example, running `notepad` in Sandboxie and sending it `Alt+F4` to kill it, or something along those lines.  Or get something basic to work outside of Sandboxie and then try and get it to work inside of Sandboxie to make sure Sandboxie itself doesn't have anything to do with your script breaking.  If the script is broken from the get-go and won't work outside of Sandboxie then it's not going to work with a program inside of Sandboxie either.